# What is a test function?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, bayesian

From what I understand, when we do hypothesis testing, we compare a test statistic, which represents some data, to a critical value that allows us to accept/reject our null hypothesis.

However, I have never seen the term 'testing function', below (which is mentioned as a criterion for a Bernstein-von Mises theorem [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.03439.pdf)). The author also explains it with the following paragraph (which I still don't understand):

[image]

...

[image]

This doesn't seem to match up with my understanding of hypothesis testing, and seems more related to [this notion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304209/what-does-test-function-mean) of test function. In this case, I don't understand how this definition has anything to do with hypothesis testing.

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your link goes to an entirely different concept of "test function."  It has no relevance to the quoted passage.  In the present case it would help to explain all the notation: presently you're requiring us to assume and guess an awful lot of the context.

Comment: @whuber The math stackexchange link is the irrelevant one?

Comment: That's right.  Same term, totally different meaning.  Actually, I'm wrong: I don't see the term "test function" anywhere in your quotation.

Comment: @whuber This wasn't obvious to me, so thank you. I am just trying to figure out what the $\phi_n(x)$ in the image refers to. I have no idea how hypothesis testing has anything to do with an integral going to 0.